# npm install giving error node js and grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying o install nodejs and grunt on my machine. I followed below steps

1. Installed `node.js` from website nodejs.

2. Installed grunt cli with command `npm install -g grunt-cli`

3. Then i used my `cwd` say `C:\projects`

4. In `cwd`, i installed sass with command `npm install grunt-contrib-sass --save-dev`

5. now after this when i run `npm install` then i got weird error. below is the screenshot.

[image]

I am struggling since yesterday with this. Please assist.

Comment: Do you have Ruby and Sass

Comment: The error message reports a problem building `node-sass`, which is not a dependency of `grunt-contrib-sass`. When you run `npm install` it tries to install every dependency listed in `package.json`. You should examine that file to ensure you are not trying to install unrelated packages.

Comment: yes i have installed ruby but not sure of sass

Comment: package.json is like as {
  "name": "APpNaME",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.3.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-legacssy": "^0.2.0",
    "grunt-pixrem": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.11.0",
    "node-bourbon": "^1.0.0"
  }
}

Comment: So this looks like an error with installing `grunt-sass` v0.11, which depends on `node-sass` v0.8. That's an old version, so you could see if the latest version (v0.18, depends on `node-sass` v2.0) installs successfully on your OS. Or, if you want to use `grunt-contrib-sass` instead of `grunt-sass` (it looks like they do the same thing), then remove the other one from your `package.json`.